# не работает background в css

Tags: html, css, background

```
.intro {
    height: 805px;
    background: url("assets/images/bg.png") 
}
```

консоль выдает ошибку net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
работает только если вписать полный путь файла начиная с C

Comment: Путь должен строиться относительно текущего расположения css-файла. Если предположить, что css-файл лежит где-нибудь в `assets/css`, значит путь должен выглядеть примерно как `url("../images/bg.png")`

Answer (score 1):

background: url("/assets/images/bg.png") слэш перед assets добавьте

Comment: попробовал, все равно не работает(

Answer (score 0):

Уберите кавычки и добавьте ";".

```
.intro {
    height: 805px;
    background: url(/assets/images/bg.png);
}
```